# Magento change sign in text Porto Theme

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

In the Porto Theme it says 'Sign in' I want to change it to 'Inloggen'
I don't know what to change in the code. Can someone help me please?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <move element="header" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
        <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
        <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

HTML output:

```
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
    <a href="https://tramag.test/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly90cmFtYWcudGVzdC8%2C/">
        Sign In    </a>
</li>
```

Thanks for your time already!

Answer (score 0):

In your Port theme (or child theme) folder at

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto
```

You will see a `i18n` folder

This contains translation files that will be used by Magento. To add a new translation add the file

```
xx_XX.csv
```

Where *xx* is your language code, i.e. `de_DE` for German.

In this file create the translation rule

```
"Sign In", "Inloggen"
```

Refresh your caches and assuming your store is set to the correct XX locale you should see the translation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have knowledge about Magento, it's best to use visualize tools.

I suggest you use `Translate Inline`: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/translate-inline.html